# Image Url's that don't have file extensions

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a wordpress theme that imports products from an API. It pulls the images and sets them as the featured image.
Here is the code that gets the image:

```
// Get the image
$post_image = (string)$item->{"image-url"};
```

Here is the code that sets the image as featured image:

```
// Update Featured image

if($post_image!= "") 
    imwb_zonpress_theme_products_set_featured_image($postId, $post_image);
```

It works fine where the url has an image extension like this:

http://media.stickyj.com/product/AX3026.jpg

The problem comes when the image url looks like this:

http://cdn.is.bluefly.com/mgen/Bluefly/prodImage.ms?productCode=336924201&width=340&height=408

The question is, how can I pull the image from this url?

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
$img_url = 'http://cdn.is.bluefly.com/mgen/Bluefly/prodImage.ms?productCode=336924201&width=340&height=408';
$save = 'filename.jpg';
file_put_contents($save, file_get_contents($img_url));
```

***output***

image

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a built-in function `file_get_contents()`, which reads the content of a file into a string.

```
<?php
//Get the file
$content = file_get_contents("http://cdn.is.bluefly.com/mgen/Bluefly/prodImage.ms?productCode=336924201&width=340&height=408");


//Store in the filesystem. $fp = fopen("http://cdn.is.bluefly.com/mgen/Bluefly/prodImage.ms?productCode=336924201&width=340&height=408", "w");
fwrite($fp, $content); fclose($fp); ?>
```